# Обязательно ли вкладывать файл конфигурации

Tags: java, android

Пытаюсь получить `tokenId` при регистрации через <kbd>Google LogIn</kbd> кнопку.

Сейчас у меня это работает так, я просто зарегистрировал в гугл консоли Web и Android и при запросе в методе

```
@NonNull
private GoogleSignInOptions getGoogleSignInOptions() {
    return new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(context.getResources().getString(R.string.server_id_test))
            .build();
}
```

использую `WebId` и все работает.

Но тут я создал еще один аккаунт в гугл консоли и там сделал то же самое и когда теперь я использую `WebId` из второго аккаунта, то получаю токой ответ

> Status{statusCode=unknown status code: 12501, resolution=null}

Почитал, что можно сделать и ничего толкового не нашел, вроде все делаю как положено, единственное что отличается так это то что некоторые разработчики скачивают `Google Configuration file` и вкладывают его в проект.

Но почему тогда в моем первом случае я не скачивал никакой файл и это работет, а во втором случае нет...

Подскажите нужно ли качать этот файл и если да то куда его вкладывать?

**От куда я беру `google-services.json` или не здесь?**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: если вы про google-services.json , то да, он должен быть в приложении

Comment: @KirillStoianov не понятно что получается... Ну вот сейчас у меня нет этого файла в приложении и все работает, только переключаю в методе `Web ID` на другой и все... не работает... Попробовал скачать этот `google-services.json` , но у меня он почему то называется  вот так  `client_secret_269322426048-o45crnrc6hnb200lhdam1uqisi0.apps.googleusercontent.com.json` . может не от туда качаю? Я его беру как показано на скриншоте я добавил в ответ... Или не так?

Comment: он должен называться google-services.json , гляньте вот по этой ссылке http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34367870/where-do-i-get-a-google-services-json

Comment: @KirillStoianov добавил я этот файл, но все равно не понятно, почему если он так нужен, мой код и без него работал отлично... А в своем коде получаете `tokenId`? Просто у меня он получается на 4 строчки... Я не уверен, что это нормально...?

Comment: уже не помню, щас не могу посмотреть!